# How to convert hours and minutes to official form with regex?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an input by user, i am asking two different times, by these way:

```
x = input('Input: ')

if data := re.search(r'^([0-9][012]?(:[0-5][0-9])? (AM|PM) to [0-9][012]?(:[0-5][0-9])? (AM|PM))', x):
    num1, age1, temp, num2, age2 = data.group(1).split()
```

what i want is, after user inputs a valid number for hours and minutes (e.g 5:24 AM to 4 PM), i want to convert them two the 24-hours form, so the output may be (05:24 AM to 16:00 PM)

ill write more examples:

```
input: 12:23 AM to 8:30 PM
output: 12:23 AM to 20:30 PM

input: 9 AM to 3 PM
output: 09:00 AM to 15:00 PM
```

### Notice:

I want to use regex only,try to have more understanding about how regex works for more complicated examples, thank you  for your help.

Comment: "AM" and "PM" in the output examples are redundant; the 24-hour format already reveals this information.

Comment: Regular expressions describe rules to match strings. They are not made to transform/convert. I think what you are trying to do does not make too much sense, to be frank. You should postprocess the regex results in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re

def f(match):
    h = int(match.group(1))
    m = match.group(2)
    if m is None:
        m = ":00"
    if match.group(3) == 'PM' and h < 12:
        h += 12
    if match.group(3) == 'AM' and h == 12:
        h = 0
    return f"{h}{m}"
    
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9][012]?)(:[0-5][0-9])? (AM|PM)')
```

Then you can use

```
x = "12:23 AM to 8:30 PM"
out = re.sub(pattern, f, x)
print(out)
```

It gives:

```
0:23 to 20:30
```

One more example:

```
y = "9 AM to 3 PM"
out = re.sub(pattern, f, y)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
9:00 to 15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex. The question is, do you want to use regex?
The tool best suited for this job would be either `strptime`, or `dateutil.parser` (not in the stdlib) for more flexibility and power:

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
def fix(string: str) -> str:
    times = [parse(time).strftime("%H:%M %p") for time in string.split(" to ")]
    return " to ".join(times)
```

Example:

```py
In [1]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [2]: def fix(string: str) -> str:
   ...:     times = [parse(time).strftime("%H:%M %p") for time in string.split(" to ")]
   ...:     return " to ".join(times)

In [3]: fix("12:23 AM to 8:30 PM")
Out[3]: '00:23 AM to 20:30 PM'

In [4]: fix("9 AM to 3 PM")
Out[4]: '09:00 AM to 15:00 PM'
```

I know the question asks for a regex solution, but posting this for any googlers who want a better, more versatile solution.